Aviation Band receiver kit - local oscillator debug
I have build this receiver from a kit bought online. It is suppose to cover something between 118-135MHz with a local oscillator that should oscillate 10.7-MHz above the selected channel. See page 8 on this document http://www.radiovilag.hu/images/air-rx-engk.pdf

I think it kind of works as I can hear some noise coming through and sometimes some faint radio station at the bottom of the band (which I assume is just an FM stations being picked up and poorly demodulated).
I want to look at the local oscillator with the oscilloscope but my cheap 10x passive probe kills the oscillation as soon as I try to attach it to pin 6 or 7 of the NE602 IC.
I am interested to see the shape of the LO signal and read the frequency. I am not interested in getting an accurate measurement of the amplitude.
Is there any way I could achieve this without an expensive active probe?

Ok, I was a bit stupid and was expecting to see a nice voltage signal picked up by the wire loop (as suggested by @timwescott).
However, as soon as I switched to FFT display and placed the wire loop over the small inductance on the board, I could clearly see the peek at the expected frequency and it is moving left and right as I adjust the tunning knob. Problem solved and I've learned a lot.


Have you tried picking up the LO to antenna leakage?

10pF~15k at 100 MHz so add a larger value series R to the probe tip with a short gnd clip or short tip with ground clip as a loop antenna.

It looks like all of the chips in this kit are "replicas" (being kind) or "fakes" (a skeptic's reality). There's no way to know their specs. I imagine that the circuit may be working fine as is, or it may be working great when genuine chips are used. This is a bit of a gamble. Every chip in this thing is definitely non-genuine. I would start by buying genuine old-stock chips. Not from Amazon, not from China, but from sources in US and Europe that you'll have to do a bit of work to find. If you can, buy whole rails - easier to tell that they are genuine if you have both a rail and the contents.

The first suggestion is one that I've seen from people smarter than me.  The second is the one I usually use in practice.
One thing
Take the clip off of the tip of the probe, and make a loop of insulated wire about 1/2 inch in diameter, straight from the tip to the ring on the prob.  This will make an inductive pickup loop.
Then set your scope on its most sensitive range, and see if there's a magic spot in the vicinity of the oscillator that picks up the signal.  Your goal is to find a current loop on the board and lay your loop over that -- without seeing the board layout I have no suggestions, but laying one edge of your loop in parallel to the tuning diode is probably a good first step.
The signal will be highly attenuated, in an uncontrolled way, but you'll at least be able to see changes in amplitude, and frequency.
Another Thing
Put a capacitor in series with C10, that's 10 to 100 times bigger, and on the cold end (i.e., between ground and C10).  This should give you a nice low-impedance point to probe without upsetting the oscillator.
Because it's a capacitive divider, the voltage division ratio will be fairly constant.  Because you know the value of C10 and the cap you added, you can calculate the ratio.  This means that at the expense of having to modify your circuit, you can get more quantitative information.
Note that if you use 10x the capacitance you'll reduce the capacitance at C10 by about 10% -- you can either live with this, or try to find a right-valued capacitance to use instead of the C10 that you took off the board.

I've added a picture with the loop. Is this what you suggested as the first option?

I've disconnected C10's ground pin and inserted a 1nF capacitor. When measuring with the scope I can't see anything but noise. Maybe I was too optimistic and the LO is not actually oscillating at all.

That loop is what I was suggesting, indeed.

You may not be getting any oscillation at all.  That capacitance will give you a ratio of about 26:1000, so a 1V p-p oscillator will give you a 26mV p-p signal at the probe.  This should be enough to show up on the scope.

if I move the NE602 IC on a copper clad board and I solder just
VCC, GND
C10, C11, C13
R4 and the inductance
Can I just leave the rest of the pins floating and hope to be able to debug just the oscillator this way? (I've added a picture of the test board)

Your question about moving the NE602 to a separate board should be asked as a different question.  But, short answer -- look in the data sheet and see if the manufacturer shows their test circuits, or some simple receiver circuit.  Test circuits generally represent a minimal functional circuit, designed to highlight one aspect of a chip's operation.
